# When returning Generic type * I get error not enough information to infer type variable T

Tags: android, oop, kotlin

I have the following code -

```kotlin
// My function - 
suspend fun leaveGroup(isSoloGroup: Boolean, groupMemberEntity: GroupMemberEntity): Resource<*> {

        val snapShot = remoteDataSource.getSnapshot(GROUP_MEMBERS_COLLECTION) {
            whereEqualTo(Constants.DatabaseProperties.ID, groupMemberEntity.id)
        }

        if (snapShot is Resource.Exception) {
            return snapShot
        }

        val delete = remoteDataSource.deleteSnapshot(snapShot.data!!)
        if (delete is Resource.Exception) {
            return delete
        }

        if (isSoloGroup.not()) {
            return (Resource.Success()) // This is where the error occurs 
        }
        // Code continues ...
    }


//My resource class - 

sealed class Resource<T> {

    abstract val data: T?

    data class Success<T>(override val data: T? = null) : Resource<T>()

    data class Exception<T>(val throwable: Throwable, override val data: T? = null) : Resource<T>()

    data class Loading<T>(val hasStarted: Boolean = false, override val data: T? = null) : Resource<T>()

}
```

And for some reason when I am returning the type `Resource<*>` the class `Resource. Success` can't be instantiated with its default value `null` and I must explicitly give it a null value - otherwise I will get the error saying  `Not enough information to infer type variable T`. Giving it null in the constructor obviously works, but this is not Clean Code and makes the default value redundant. What am I missing?

Comment: `return Resource.Success<Nothing>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html) type in the type system, which has no values, it cannot be instantiated.

Because Nothing has no values, `Nothing?` is actually the type that captures only the `null` value in Kotlin.

That is, when you declare something like this:

```kotlin
val someVariable = null
```

The inferred type of someVariable is `Nothing?`

So if you wish to store the null, you have to give it a type (compiler cannot infer it directly as it can be anything like `String?`, `Int?`, etc.), So giving it explicit `Nothing?` is more appropriate.

```kotlin
if (isSoloGroup.not()) {
    return Resource.Success<Nothing>()
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. Understanding from what you said, in other words what I was trying to do is get a null value out of a possible JavaScript-like Undefined which is impossible, therefore the error occurred.